# Make multi-subselect more efficient?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I've got a select query that returns the next record alphabetically with relation to the given ID:

```
SELECT * 
FROM contacts 
WHERE client_id = 22844 
AND deleted_at IS NULL 
AND 
( 
  ( 
    last_name = (
      SELECT last_name 
      FROM contacts 
      WHERE client_id = 22844 AND id = 717604
    ) 
    AND first_name > (
      SELECT first_name 
      FROM contacts 
      WHERE client_id = 22844 AND id = 717604
    )
  ) 
  OR ( 
    last_name > (
      SELECT last_name 
      FROM contacts 
      WHERE client_id = 22844 AND id = 717604
    ) 
  ) 
) 

ORDER BY last_name, first_name 
LIMIT 1
```

There are individual indices on first_name, last_name, deleted_at and client_id.

Is there any way to rewrite this to be more efficient?  It currently takes about 250ms - 300ms when a particular client has about 3000 contacts.

Currently using mysql 5.5

EDIT:

Turns out to be an order of magnitude faster if I leave out the `deleted_at IS NULL` condition.  I might just stop using soft-deletion and move deleted records to an archive instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative method.  It enumerates the rows after the desired row is seen:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM (SELECT c.*,
             (@rn := if(c.id = 717604 or @rn > 0, @rn + 1, 0) as rn                
      FROM contacts c CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @rn := 0) params
      WHERE c.client_id = 22844 AND c.deleted_at IS NULL 
      ORDER BY c.last_name, c.first_name
     ) c
WHERE rn = 2;
```

For this query, you want indexes on `contacts(client_id, deleted_at, last_name, first_name)`.

EDIT:

The performance on your query seems reasonable.  However, the best indexes are `contacts(client_id, id, last_name)` and `contacts(client_id, id, first_name)`

Comment: Hmm, with your query and index, `explain` is still telling me it's using `intersect(client_id, deleted_at)` for the index.  I'm also getting that same intersect index with my query, with or without the additional indexes you suggested?

Comment: @jemminger . . . Curious.  The `where` clause essentially consists of two equality conditions, so the index should be used for both the `where` and the `order by`.  Perhaps if you dropped the index with only two columns, MySQL would be smarter.

Comment: there aren't actually any compound indexes right now.  It's choosing to intersect two individual indexes, `client_id` and `deleted_at`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  b.*
    FROM  
      ( SELECT  last_name, first_name
            FROM  contacts
            WHERE  client_id = 22844
              AND  id = 717604 
      ) AS a
    JOIN  contacts AS b
    WHERE  deleted_at IS NULL
      AND    b.last_name >= a.last_name
      AND  ( b.first_name > a.first_name
         OR  b.last_name > a.last_name 
           )
    ORDER BY  b.last_name, b.first_name
    LIMIT  1; 
-- and have these indexes on contacts:
INDEX(client_id, id),
INDEX(last_name, first_name)
```